# Not able to install scikit-survival package. Get a Pyasn1 error and a "dill' Error

Tags: pyasn1, scikit-survival

I have been trying to install scikit-survival package for survival analysis but whenever I try to do this I get the error shown below.

Error

`pyasn1-modules 0.1.5 has requirement pyasn1<0.4.0,>=0.3.4, but you'll have pyasn1 0.1.9 which is incompatible.`
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZavXw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got too old pyasn1 installed on your system or in your virtualenv. You need to upgrade pyasn1 to match the requirements. If it is a system-wide pyasn1 package which is old, I'd not touch it but run scikit in a virtualenv.

Comment: @llya How can I do that?